# Tableview reload data not working when using afnetworking 2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking-2

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
[manager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",TIC_URL,@"list_messages.php"] parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"responseObject %@",responseObject);
     if (![[responseObject valueForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
         marrChat = [responseObject valueForKey:@"data"];

         [self.tblChat reloadData];


         if (marrChat.count > 0)
         {
             [self.tblChat scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:marrChat.count-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
         }

     } 

     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
     [CommonFunctions showNoNetworkError];
     HideHUD;
 }];
```

Comment: reload data in main thread

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self.tblChat reloadData];
});    not working........

Comment: Are you sure that your response of api is success not failure.

Comment: success  nirav..  and marrChat array contains Objects ...

Comment: not working above link .......

Comment: Are you sure marrChat here is an instance variable not a local/shadow variable.

Comment: sure, it  is instance variable....

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the line with reloadData is called?

Answer (score 0):

Write the `[self.tblChat reloadData];` in the main queue.

```
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tblChat reloadData];

});
```

Comment: not working suraj.....

Comment: by using this solution...whats the error you find?

Comment: [self.tblChat reloadData]; not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
        [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```